# como realizar dicha consulta en sql server 2012

Tags: sql

hola necesito hacer esta consulta en sql pero nose como realizarla queria saber si me podian ayudar.
la consulta seria "Mostrar el promedio de desaprobados en cada instancia." lo cual la instancia en mi caso seria la tabla tipo :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui dejo el der:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: hola ! debajo te deje como me sale la consulta. porque la verdad no la puedo sacar. desde ya se los agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score -1):

hola si aca paso la consulta redatada anteriormente que seria: "Mostrar el promedio de desaprobados en cada instancia."

y la consulta la realizo de esta manera:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me podrian ayudar a ver cual es el error para sacar el promedio de desaprobados

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que buscar que la consulta te devuelva algo parecido a esta tabla:
[image: Así sería el resultado a buscar]

La cuarta columna de esta tabla se calcula en base a los valores de las otras 2 anteriores.

Pero **OJO**: porque en tu consulta estarías calculando todas las evaluaciones de todas las materias de la Universidad y de todos los Cursos y de todas las carreras.
Así que también deberías filtrar esos datos.

Para eso la tabla que guarda las evaluaciones es la más importante. No la de los alumnos.

```
 SELECT tipo.nombre ,  
        COUNT (CASE WHEN evaluaciones.nota < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TD ,
        COUNT (CASE WHEN evaluaciones.nota >=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TG ,
        (TD/TG)*100 AS PED 
            FROM Evaluacion INNER JOIN tipo ON Evaluacion.idTipo = tipo.idTipo 
                    GROUP BY tipo.nombre
```

En principio lo que pediste debería ser algo parecido a esto de arriba.

Pero para que tenga sentido deberías incluir también el `JOIN` con la tabla PLANILLA y así poder filtrar por `idMateria` y `idCurso`.

```
HAVING planilla.idMateria=Valor1 AND planilla.idCurso=Valor2
```

Espero que le sirva.